# Flask delete routes added with add_url()

Tags: python, flask

at app init i'm dynamically loading URL's from the DB, adding them with `app.add_url()`.
As the behavior is CMS like, my user can delete or change the url for some pages so i need to sometimes delete a mapping or reload all url mappings.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask (which relies on [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/)) is designed to allow the user to easily add, not delete, routes. However you can try to delete routes yourself; each route is added to `url_map` in the [`Flask.add_url_rule()` method](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/9e41eca7f839db16cdf064f827fada0cabf6f54f/flask/app.py#L1047). It is probably enough to remove the route from `Map._rules` and `Map._rules_by_endpoint` (see the [`Map.add()`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/8a2f3a8fb8365121d7069b2edb0f83ae852b1c93/werkzeug/routing.py#L1198) method) and call [`Map.update()`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/8a2f3a8fb8365121d7069b2edb0f83ae852b1c93/werkzeug/routing.py#L1337) with `_remap`.

But this will not work in general, for example when creating a route that delegates to a view function in a separate `dict`:

```py
    _routes = {}

    @app.route('/<path:url>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def route(url):
        handler = _routes.get(url, None)
        if handler is not None:
            return handler()
        abort(404)
```