# How to recreate/reload app when external config/database changes in Flask

Tags: flask, plotly-dash

I’m making a server to convert Rmarkdown to Dash apps. The idea is parse all params in the rmd file and make corresponding Dash inputs. Then add a submit button which compile the rmd to html somewhere and iframe back. I use an external database to store the info for rmd paths so user can dynamically add files. The problem is when a rmd file changes, the server has to reparse the file and recreate the app and serve at the same url. I don’t have an elegant solution. Right now I’m doing something like this.

```
server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route(“rmd/path:path”):
def convert_rmd_to_dash(path):
  file = get_file_path_from_db(path)
  mtime = get_last_modified_time(file)
  cached_app, cached_mtime = get_cache(path)
  if cached_mtime == mtime:
    return cached_app
  inputs = parse_file(file)
  app = construct_dash_app(inputs)
  return app.index()

def construct_dash_app(inputs):
  app = dash.Dash(
      name,
      server=server,
      routes_pathname_prefix=’/some_url_user_will_never_use/’ + file_name + time.time())
  app.layout = …
  …
  return app
```

It works but I get many routing rules under /some_url_user_will_never_use. Directly overwriting rmd/path might be possible but feels hacky based on Stackoveflow’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129217/flask-delete-routes-added-with-add-url). Is there a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: You may ask this within plotly community forum. It's very active and responses there are richer over there on such specific issues. :)

Comment: I did and got no response. That's why I'm here. https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-recreate-app-when-external-config-changes/23525

Comment: Too bad to hear, that wasn't my intent..

Comment: Np. I think this is a general question for Flask too. Curious why no one could answer or tell me no it's not possible.